# how to validate a sponsored post against the "approved partner" list of the sponsor

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

if we create a post on a page (A) which is tagged as sponsored by (B) and page (B) has "Page Approvals" turned on.

which endpoint do we call to find out if (A) is a "Approve Page" (on the white list) of (B).

because if  (A)  is not a  "Approve Page" of (B) the post will fail, 
so we want to do this before trying to post this content, which prevents the post from failing.

if that makes sense?

we have administrator permissions on (A) .

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/212566145960789?helpref=page_content

I think maybe query i'm looking for is:

https://graph.facebook.com/(B)/crosspost_whitelisted_pages ? 
but we need permissions for B, which we don't have?

so basically something like

```
 A.isOnWhitelist(B) ;
```

using permissions of A